# What should I aim to learn over the next 8 months?

Tags: programming-languages

I am currently taking a year off between high school and college (computer science).

I'm pretty good with Visual basic (unfortunately, this is the only language my school offered in High School). I've dabbled in some PHP, and have pretty good knowledge of broad programming principals and concepts.

I'm more interested in web programming then conventional, but I'd like to do both.

What are some good languages I should pick up over this next eight months, and what are some good, (tough but attainable) goals I should set for myself in this time frame?

Thanks!

Comment: This is a subjective software development question.  Wouldn't it fit better on http://programmers.stackexchange.com?

Answer (score 2):

Read some books.

- *The Pragmatic Programmer. From Journeyman to Master*, Thomas, Hunt - to make your brain think in a pragmatic way, not PHP or other technology way. PHP or Ruby will die, the knowledge from this book won't as it's universal.
- *Apprenticeship Patterns*, Hoover, Oshineye - to plan your career, get to know what's important, what to avoid and what to do to make yourself better.

Answer (score 1):

If it's web programming you're after, you have three top contenders at the moment for web development (in no particular order):

- ASP.Net
- Ruby on Rails
- PHP

If you've been schooled on VB, the ASP.Net might offer the most familiar development environment, but all three are very marketable.

As far as personal development and goal-setting is concerned and given you only have 8 months to work with, I'd say you want to get intimate with the following concepts and how the work in practice:

- unit testing
- CSS
- JavaScript

See if you can write your first practical application.  This will set you up incredibly well for future employment if you can say you actually delivered something (grades are good, but delivery and experience is better).

If you really want to aim high, see if you can secure a casual part-time job at a software shop.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Interestingly enough, I just finished up a three-month full-time work placement at a startup developing a PHP app. That's where my dabbling comes in!

Answer (score 1):

Ruby on Rails is pretty cool and easy to learn esp. if you are after web development.
AJAX can help you with giving your web page some cool features.
I would suggest you to get the book : [Agile Development with Ruby on Rails](http://pragprog.com/titles/rails3/agile-web-development-with-rails). It will help you get started.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to focus on the language that the college you will be attending will be teaching their low-level classes in.  this way, you can have a bit of a head start on the class, giving you more time for your other classes.

I think most colleges currently start off in Java. You should be able to find that out with a bit of research.

Answer (score 1):

If it is good grades and ease of programming in college you seek, learn the language of choice of the school you plan on attending.  Most schools stick with one primary language for the introductory classes as many universities teach conceptual programming.  I think the most common languages right now for universities to teach are Java and C++ as both offer good, cross-platform introductions into object-oriented concepts such as polymorphism and aggregation.

If you are attending a technical college or community college for an associates degree, those are normally more applied and teach "how to program a website with PHP" or similar.  In that case, you may focus on the fundamentals of the class such as how do web application work, learn about compilers and how they work, etc.  Things they won't teach you but are valuable to know in the real world.

If you want to parlay this knowledge into a job writing web applications, you must consider where you may work.  Different industries have accepted different languages.  Many young businesses and industries accept newer languages such as PHP, Ruby, etc.  Some shops are purely Windows (there are a lot) and do much of their web apps in .NET.  Then there are still a number of middleware-based solutions such as WebSphere, WebLogic, JBoss, etc.  There are also some in-between things that are still web focused such as PeopleTools programming.  You may also consider learning about web application scaling.

If I were you, I would focus on a primary skill you already posess, and nurture that so that you become highly skilled.  You can't master everything, but being an expert in something makes you desirable.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'd start looking at data structures and algorithms, they are the building blocks of good computer science knowledge, as most of them will make use of the majority of features of any given programming language, and as you learn to implement these in the chosen language, you'll get to grips with the programming language.

I heartily agree with Muad'Dib.  Look at what language the course is using, and start using that language.  If it's C++, then you can get utilities like Cygwin for Windows where you can develop in a virtual linux box without having to re-wipe your computer.

If it's Visual Studio stuff, then there's the MSDN Express stuff that's free from Microsoft, although it's a bit of a download.

Also, the Pragmatic Programmer is a MUST READ!  It's full of great advice, and you're at the very best stage to start picking up good habits, start doing that now, and you'll go far in the programming world.

Hope that helps.